# What to do when browser stays in waiting state

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am thying to write a simple dart Angular application.

I frequently find that when I try and test the app using dartium

1. the raw static page is displayed
2. the console display

   [web] GET /lightning.html => lightning|web/lightning.html
   [web] GET /lightning.css => lightning|web/lightning.css
   [web] GET /packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.min.js => shadow_dom|lib/shadow_dom.min.js
   [web] GET /packages/browser/dart.js => browser|lib/dart.js
3. the status of the browser is 'Waiting for 127.0.0.1
4. I get a happy little 'please wait' icon in the browser tab
5. And nothing happens

Obviously I have broken something. How do I go about finding out what?

Thanks
Richard

Comment: I don't know it this helps but I want to note that `shadow_dom` is deprecated since a very long time. Please use `web_components` instead. I have this also very often lately that the browser looks like it still waits for some response (spinning circle in the tab) but the page looks like all is loaded and rendered properly - I'm not Angular.dart but Polymer.

Comment: I filed a bug for this a few days ago https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20626

Comment: I should stress - nothing happens. And I mean nothing. None of the angular magic happens. dead. dead dead

Comment: Can you make the project available at GitHub. Its hard to tell without looking at the code.